# setting solid color in radio button tcl tk

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

i want "LED" kind of radio buttons placed next to each other.
I used this command to set the color and disabled the state.

```
radiobutton .field1 -disabledforeground green -state "disabled"
radiobutton .field2 -disabledforeground red -state "disabled"
radiobutton .field3 -disabledforeground green -state "disabled"

grid .field1 -row 0 -column 1
grid .field2 -row 0 -column 2
grid .field3 -row 0 -column 3
```

I want something like led kind of. Filling solid green color and turning off the indicator inside the radio button.

I tried "-indicatoron" setting to false. It doesnt work still.

My Application will look like this,
[image]

Code:

```
proc changeDisabledColor {w color} {
    puts "gng inside"
    $w configure -disabledforeground $color
}

set rowList [list "row1" "row2" "row3" "row4" "row5" "row6"]
set colList [list "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6"]

label .textNames -text "Description"
grid .textNames -row 0 -column 0
foreach temItem $colList {
    label .field$temItem -text "col $temItem"
    grid .field$temItem -row 0 -column $temItem
}

set rowIndex 1

foreach item $rowList {
    set colIndex 0
    label .$item -text "$item"
    grid .$item -row $rowIndex -column $colIndex
    foreach temCol $colList {
        set frameId "frame_$item\_$temCol"
        frame .$frameId -borderwidth 2 -relief ridge
        grid .$frameId -row $rowIndex -column [expr $colIndex + 1]
        radiobutton .$frameId.field1 -disabledforeground green -state "disabled"
        radiobutton .$frameId.field2 -disabledforeground red -state "disabled"
        radiobutton .$frameId.field3 -disabledforeground green -state "disabled"

        grid .$frameId.field1 -row $rowIndex -column [expr $colIndex + 1]
        grid .$frameId.field2 -row $rowIndex -column [expr $colIndex + 2]
        grid .$frameId.field3 -row $rowIndex -column [expr $colIndex + 3]
        incr colIndex
    }
    incr rowIndex
}

bind .frame_row3_2.field3 <Map> [list after 10000 {changeDisabledColor %W blue}]
```

Expected Output:

[image]

Is it possible to make radio button look like this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish. You have two things in your question right? 1. About the colour, 2 about the alignment. Can you clarify how it should look, maybe add another picture in the question for this?

Comment: Hi, i have updated the question. Added the expected output also.

Comment: Do you need to have the radiobuttons disabled? You can get the buttons to look like what you drew, but the buttons have to be active. Clicking on the button will temporarily show a coloured dot with a white background however.

Comment: I managed to find out which proc is involved when you press the button, so if you want, you can also 'hack' it so you don't get any response from the button if it is normal and is clicked.

Comment: Can you tell me how to hack it?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, what you are trying to do is not portable. It will not work on all platforms, some of which override the way that radiobuttons look quite thoroughly. You'd be better off using labels and configuring the images in them. Except…

Secondly, it's looking like it will create a large number of widgets. That's usually an indication that you're not doing things the right way. Such as…

Thirdly, it's really not that difficult to use a canvas, and that gives you both efficiency and flexibility.

```
pack [canvas .c]

# Some helper procedures
proc makeClickableDot {x y bgVariable callback} {
    upvar #0 $bgVariable background
    set coords [list $x $y [expr {$x+10}] [expr {$y+10}]]
    set id1 [.c create oval $coords -fill $background -outline grey75]
    set id2 [.c create arc $coords -style arc -start 45 -extent 180 -outline black]
    .c bind $id1 <1> $callback
    .c bind $id2 <1> $callback
    trace add variable background write [list clickableDotWrite $bgVariable $id1]
}
proc clickableDotWrite {bgVariable id args} {
    upvar #0 $bgVariable background
    .c itemconf $id -fill $background
}

# Now we can just make our variables and dots
set rowList [list "row1" "row2" "row3" "row4" "row5" "row6"]
set colList [list "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6"]

set Y 10
foreach row $rowList {
    set X 10
    foreach col $colList {
        set cell($row,$col,1) green
        # It's a dumbass callback!
        makeClickableDot $X $Y cell($row,$col,1) [list set cell($row,$col,1) red]
        incr X 15
        set cell($row,$col,2) blue
        makeClickableDot $X $Y cell($row,$col,2) [list set cell($row,$col,2) yellow]
        incr X 15
        set cell($row,$col,3) magenta
        makeClickableDot $X $Y cell($row,$col,3) [list set cell($row,$col,3) cyan]
        incr X 15
    }
    incr Y 15
}
```

OK, that's *very* colourful and you'll need a bit more work to tune it to how you want (I've not totally nailed the look, the callbacks are dumb and you probably need a second array to hold some sort of state) but it's the core of it all and all you need to do after setting it up is manipulate variables. The traces take care of reflecting the changes to those to the GUI. Which is nice, and how Tk is supposed to work most of the time.